# Can I create a WordPress view to create a JSON file to be used by javascript in a page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, d3.js, drupal-7

I am attempting to convert a Drupal site which creates a dynamic JSON file from a custom content type that is used by javascript to create a map (which uses D3 code). Is this possible in WordPress?

Comment: [Here's an example](https://webdevstudios.com/2015/07/09/creating-simple-json-endpoint-wordpress/) of creating a custom endpoint that serves custom JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. I believe you have REST API available by default in WP. Can you specify the question?

**EDIT:**

You can see available endpoints by going to `yousite.com/wp-json`.
By adding custom post type it is automatically available in REST, name of the endpoint is by default same as name of the custom post type you are adding, you can change it by adding `rest_base` property in custom post type definition.
You can find more on this here https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/

Comment: My Drupal site has a custom content type. This content type is used by a Drupal view to create a JSON file. This JSON file is entered into a javascript on another page to draw a map.

Comment: What is an endpoint (I am not an expert in WordPress terminology)?

Comment: I'll see if I can figure out how to use it before I ask any more questions. Thanks.

Comment: When you go to `yousite.com/wp-json`, you get json with available routes, every route returns json. For example if you go to `yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages`, you get a JSON with all the pages that you've created in WP. By going to `yoursite.com/wp-json//wp/v2/pages/10`, where 10 is page id, you get JSON of that page. Same goes for custom post types.

Comment: What is a Rest base?

Comment: It's a property you can define when adding custom post type. For example `'rest_base' => 'my-post-type'`.
Then it is available to you at `yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/my-post-type`.

Comment: That worked ... when I tried before I did not use "wp-json/wp/v2/".  Many thanks but can I edit the json file? there is a lot there that I do not want?

Comment: Can I calculate some fields (e.g. total of custom fields) and create the JSON from the output of the calculations - would using something like Query Wrangler to to do that?

Comment: Try thinking in terms of WP not Drupal.
Take a look at this plugin https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/.
It can be added to REST API with this https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api plugin.

Comment: I am trying to understand how to build pages with maps that display numbers that are the total or count of individual custom fields. These totals are for a group of custom fields. In my application the totals/counts are calculated by a view and it generates a JSON file that contains one row for each group. I use this JSON file in a javascript (actually 2 JSON files one is a GeoJSON file used to build the map).

Comment: Here is an example http://stopplastics.ca/44-ward-count The counts are the total number of postcards that were signed in a ward.

Comment: Probably last comment ... it looks like the solutions Jaroslav use javascript. With a Drupal view I do not need to know javascript. The only reason I use javascript is to generate maps. I can do many calculations such as this without javascript.